# How t show $f=g$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

How to show $f=g$ almost everywhere

Let two real-valued measurable functions $f$ and $g$ be such that for any measurable set $E$ the integrals $\int_E f\,d\mu$  and  $\int_E g\,d\mu$ coincide.

Could you please help.

It seems obvious. we could define the integrals as charges. can we do sth from here. but I do not know how to approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f = g$ a.e. does not hold, then one of the sets

$$A_n := \{x \in X \mid f(x) \geq g(x) + 1/n\}$$

or

$$B_n := \{x \in X \mid g(x) \geq f(x) + 1/n\}$$

has positive measure (why?).

Now assume that $X$ is $\sigma$-finite (or semifinite, otherwise the statement is in general wrong).

Then there exists a subset $E \subset A_n$ or $E \subset B_n$ of positive, finite(!) measure (why?).

Conclude that $\int_E f \, d\mu \neq \int_E g \, d\mu$.

EDIT: As observed in the comments, it is not that easy to show that $\int_E f \,d\mu \neq \int_E g \, d\mu$ if one does not know that the two integrals are actually finite. But to ensure this, we can modify the sets $A_n,B_n$ to

$$
A_n ' = A_n \cap \{x \mid |f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq n\}
$$
(similar for $B_n '$) and then use the proof as described above.

Comment: So you say $\mu( \lbrace x\in X :|f(x)-g(x)|>1/n\rbrace)>\epsilon_0$ for some $\epsilon_0>0$ since they are not equal. Then we can find a measurable(!) set $E\subset \lbrace x\in X :|f(x)-g(x)|>1/n\rbrace)$ which has a finite positive measure $M$. Then $\int_E |f-g|d\mu \geq M.(1/n)$

Am I right?

Comment: Essentially yes. But I split your set $\{x \in X \,|\, |f(x) - g(x)| > 1/n\}$ in the two different sets $A_n$, $B_n$, because you only know that $\int_E f d\mu = \int_E g d\mu$ and not that $\int_E |f-g| d\mu = 0$ (in that case the proof would be easier). Assume that $E \subset A_n$ has positive measure (this implicitely entails measurability). Then $\int_E f d\mu \geq \int_E g d\mu + \mu(E)/n > \int_E g d\mu$, contradiction.

Comment: Can we directly say that $A_n$ has a positve measured subset(of course as you said it would imply measurabilty)? I don't think we can assume that directly.

Comment: No, you can't. Thats why your claim is wrong in general. Consider e.g. $X = \{1\}$ with measure $\mu({1}) = \infty$ (fill in the details) and $f \equiv 1$, $g \equiv 2$. Then for $E \subset X$ we either have $E = \emptyset$, so $\int_E f = 0 = \int_E g$ or $E = \{1\}$, in which case both integrals equal $\infty$. But NOT $f = g$ a.e. Thus, we assume that $X$ is semi-finite (see also here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234898/prove-that-every-sigma-finite-measure-is-semifinite ).

Comment: I changed \,|\, to \mid, which I take to be standard usage.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I did not know that.

Comment: @PhoemueX In the second comment you say $ \int_E g d\mu + \mu(E)/n > \int_E g d\mu$  how do you know that $\int_E g d\mu$ is finite? Thanks!

Comment: @ErginSuer: Very Good question! I do not know that ;) But you can modify the set $A_n$ to $A_n \cap \{x \mid |f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq n\}$ and then it is clear that the integral is finite. This at least works in the case that $f,g$ assume only values in $\Bbb{R}$ (and not $\pm\infty$).

Comment: @PhoemueX I couldn't see why $A_n '$ or $B_n '$ is a set of measure nonzero and why $\int_E fd\mu$ or $\int_E gd\mu$ is finite. Thanks!

Comment: Assume that **each** of these sets has measure zero (we only need that at least one of them has positive measure to arrive at our wanted contradiction). Then use the fact that countable unions of measure zero sets have measure zero to conclude $f = g$ a.e. Finally, $E \subset A_n'$ (or $E \subset B_n '$) is of finite measure. Hence, $\int_E |f|d\mu \leq \int_E |f| + |g| d\mu \leq n \cdot \mu(E) < \infty$. Analogously for $\int_E |g| d\mu$.