# Two functions with same interal are the same function?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, functions

I don't know if this is true but I would like it to be:
Suppose $(\Omega,\mathbb{B},\mu)$ is a probalility space, where $\mathbb{B}$ is atomless, and $\mathbb{A}$ is non tirvial $\sigma$-algebra contained in $\mathbb{B}$. If $f,g$ are two $\mathbb{A}$-measurable functions and for all $A\in\mathbb{A}$ we got that $\int_A fd\mu=\int_A gd\mu$ then $f=g$ a.s ? 
If this isn't true I could say something about $f$ and $g$ ?

Comment: I think you can leave out the edited extra conditions (atomless, non-trivial). Maybe they were inspired by my wrong answer. I overlooked the condition that $f,g$ are $\mathbb A$- measurable.

Comment: Yes, the essence of the proof can be found in the linked question, but I would not call this a duplicate of that question. It is in my view more a question in the sense of: "uptil how far can this be extended to sub $\sigma$-algebra's?" Recognizable! I plead for reopening the question.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $\mathbb A=\{\varnothing,\Omega\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra contained in $\mathbb B$.

In that case the equalities you mention only tell us that $f$ and $g$ have the same mean.

This conclusion can be drawn also if $\mathbb A$ contains more elements, but in general (i.e. without any further conditions) it is the only one that has a justification.

---

**edit**:

What's above the line is wrong as commented by **Kabo** (thank you).

If $\mu$ is a probability measure on measurable space $(\Omega,\mathbb B)$ and $f,g:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ are $\mathbb B$-measurable functions then :  $$\forall B\in\mathbb B\;\left[\int_Bf\;d\mu=\int_Bg\;d\mu\right]\implies\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)=g(\omega)\})=1\tag1$$which is a well known theorem (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803082/75923)).

If $\mathbb A$ denotes a $\sigma$-algebra with $\mathbb A\subseteq\mathbb B$ then measure $\nu$ on $\mathbb A$ prescribed by $A\mapsto\mu(A)$ is evidently a probability measure on measurable space $(\Omega,\mathbb A)$. So if $f,g$ are $\mathbb A$-measurable then application of $(1)$ tells us that:$$\forall A\in\mathbb A\;\left[\int_Af\;d\nu=\int_Ag\;d\nu\right]\implies\nu(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)=g(\omega)\})=1\tag2$$

This with:

- $\nu(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)=g(\omega)\})=\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)=g(\omega)\})$
- $\int_Af\;d\nu=\int_Af\;d\mu$
- $\int_Ag\;d\nu=\int_Af\;d\mu$

so we can rewrite $(2)$ as:$$\forall A\in\mathbb A\;\left[\int_Af\;d\mu=\int_Ag\;d\mu\right]\implies\mu(\{\omega\in\Omega\mid f(\omega)=g(\omega)\})=1$$

Comment: This is wrong. You forgot the assumption that $f$ and $g$ are $\mathbb A$ measurable.

Answer (score 2):

We can conclude that $f=g$ a.e.  Apply the hypothesis to $\{x: f(x) >g(x)+\frac 1 n\}$ and conclude that this set must have measure $0$. This gives $ f \leq g$ a.e.. Similarly. $g \leq f$ a.e..